# Account activator link is a use case for HMAC?

Tags: php, security

I'm using PHP and need to design the activator link

```
$data = $user->email; 
$key = $user->token; // bin2hex(openssl_random_pseud_bytes(16));
$hmac = hash_hmac( 'sha256', $data, $key );
```

So, would send to user the follow url

```
hostname/account/confirm/7c7b0f24eff74902cb07e900b07a0cafc8fccfa5d2704fb92aaf3b91e9774f98
```

This way is good idea?

If true, `sha256` is best choice for `hash_hmac()` on this situation? Particularly, i would appreciate one string with `length <= 24`

Comment: password_hash() with salt would be better,in this case

Comment: Why do you need `hash_hmac` at all? Why not just use `$user->token` directly as your email activation key?

Comment: @FoxWilson hilarious, i used `bin2hex(openssl_random_pseud_bytes(16));` just to illustrate my question and appears that's a great solution

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR:** You don't need to use `hash_hmac()` for this use case. You can use the token directly.

If `$user->token` is generated securely (n.b. you want `random_bytes()`, not `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()`, due to [collisions in OpenSSL's random number generator](https://github.com/ramsey/uuid/issues/80)), then it's a secure random value and an attacker has no way of knowing it without hacking the table.

#### Where you'd want to use HMAC

If you want to authenticate some cleartext data sent to your user's email address, you could use HMAC for this purpose.

For example: On registration, if you need to present users with an option (e.g. GDPR consent), you can create the following two URLs tied to the same token, like so:

```
$hmacYes = hash_hmac('sha256', 'yes', $user->token);
$hmacNo = hash_hmac('sha256', 'no', $user->token);
```

Then you can have two links for each option, and send the links like so:

```
* `hostname/account/confirm/yes${hmacYes}`
* `hostname/account/confirm/no${hmacNo}`
```

And then you can parse out the HMAC value:

```
if (!preg_match('/^(yes|no)(.*)$/', $urlParam, $matches) {
    throw new SecurityException('bad url');
}
$choice = $matches[1];
$hmac =   $matches[2];

$recalc = hash_hmac('sha256', $choice, $user->token);
if (!hash_equals($recalc, $mac)) {
    throw new SecurityException('bad url');
}
// Now you know $choice is from a genuine user email
```

However, if you only need challenge-response authentication, then a secure random token is sufficient.